# Product images not showing

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, product-images, frontend

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour: all the product images are present if I edit a product on the backend. But if I visit the product list in the backend or frontend, or the product view in frontend, I see no images.

Any ideas on how to resolve the problem?

- Magento version: 2.3.4
- Running on Nginx
- Permissions on files correctly set

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was an issue with permissions on directories, not on files.
Set to drwxr-xr-x and got them working again.

Answer (score 1):

This can be happened due to many reasons. please try each solution one by one.

**Solution1:**
try to increase memory_limit, after that run the Nginx server

**Solution 2 (try this if 1st one does not reflect images on frontend):**
try to run this command =>

```
sudo php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

it will take some time & then run

```
 sudo php bin/magento c:c
```

**Solution 3**
If both will not work then this can be happened due to the 3rd party module please check & if anyone related to product then disable each module & check again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, see my answer.